# How to pass the array data in one selected option field in html to another select option field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic, ejs, mern

I have multiple product category documents in a MongoDB collection, each with an array. While passing this collection into ejs file in nodejs, I've created a select field to select the category and I want to show the array in that document in another select field. The second select field options want to change according to the category name.

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" class="form-control">
     <% if(category.length>0){ for(let i=0;i<category.length;i++){%>
            <option id="cat">
                  <%= category[i].name %>
             </option>
     <% }}else{ %>
               <option value="">No categories</option>
     <% } %>
 </select>
              
  
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="size">Size</label>
     <select id="size" class="form-control">
        <option value="">M</option>
     </select>
</div>

How can I get the array in the first select field to the second select field?
enter image description here
```